# IFormfile doesn't send latest file

Tags: asp.net-core, file-upload, iformfile

I'm working on an ASP.NET core web application where I have to import some data from an Excel file. I've build a web page with a form on it that uses model binding to an IFormFile.

```
<input id="importfile" asp-for="ImportFile" type="file" accept=".xls, .xlsx" />

public IFormFile ImportFile { set; get; }
```

When I select an Excel file and submit the form the first time the file is uploaded and received on the backend; no problem.
I then first check the cells inside the Excel file, and when it's not as I expect I give back an error. The user can correct the Excel file via Microsoft Excel, and press the submit button again (the file is still selected).
What happens then is that not the corrected file is received on the backend, but the old file !! ... and that's not what I want, I want to receive the corrected latest file. How can I achieve that ?

Comment: this looks like a client-side issue rather than a server-side issue. Your browser actually cannot detect the file change or the old file is cached somehow. So either the user has to re-select the file or at best I think you can reset the file field at the time receiving an error back from the server. That's way the user has to re-select the file by himself and cannot miss that step (because it's required). I'm not so sure about a better solution (in which the user does not have to re-do that selection).

Comment: What is the relationship between correct the Excel file and press the submit button? Whether the file has been checked and submitted to the browser, why should it be checked after being submitted to the browser?

Comment: @Karney. there is a mandatory cell. If this cell hasn't been filled the submit reports back an error, and the user should correct the Excel file and submit the corrected file again.